# Remove comma from last element in loop

Tags: jquery, css, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In a rails app view I'm outputting data from an Array separated by commas. How to remove the comma from the last element? I could do:

```
html = ""
answer.first.selected_answers.each do |sa|
  if answer.first.selected_answers[-1] == sa
    html << content_tag(:span, "#{sa.possible_answer.text}", class: 'answer')
  else
    html << content_tag(:span, "#{sa.possible_answer.text}, ", class: 'answer')
  end
end
html.html_safe
```

Is there a more elegant way? Maybe using JQuery? Or CSS `last-child`?

Comment: I've always found it to be easier to not print it in the first place. If you had an index available, you could conditionally add the comma when the index != `selected_answers`'s length - 1.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can use `join` method.

for example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7].join(", ").split(" ")
=> ["1,", "2,", "3,", "4,", "5,", "6,", "7"]
```

for your codes, maybe can write like this:

```
answer.first.selected_answers.map { |sa| sa.possible_answer.text }.join(", ").split(" ")
      .map{ |t| content_tag(:span, t, class: 'answer') }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do anything different, if I'm understanding the question. If you're worried that there is a trailing comma it will be handled with String.split(',') method.

```
irb(main):001:0> str = '1,2,3,4,'
=> "1,2,3,4,"
irb(main):002:0> arr = str.split(',')
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

The array does not recognize the commas as important, it is a composite datatype that is a collection of other datatypes. So to output join the elements together.

```
irb(main):004:0> arr.join(', ')
=> "1, 2, 3, 4"
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, perhaps I didn't phrase the problem well enough. I've added the comment in the view helper method to format the output nicely. @pangpang's answer does what I need with a little amending.

Answer (score 0):

The join method joins the all the elements in the array with the given parameter, in this case (a comma followed by a space) and returns one long string e.g. `'a, b'`. Notice the last element `('b')` is not followed by a comma and a space. The split method turns the string into an array of elements e.g. `['a, ', 'b']`. Again notice how only the first element includes a comma followed by a space. The second map loops through the array using the rails helper `content_tag` to provide some html code for each element. The content tag is appended to the html variable for displaying in the view.

```
answer.first.selected_answers.map { |sa| sa.possible_answer.text }.join(", ").split("").map do |t| 
  html << content_tag(:span, t, class: 'answer') 
end
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: The join method joins the all the elements in the array with the given parameter, in this case (a comma followed by a space) and returns one long string e.g. 'a, b'. Notice the last element ('b') is not followed by a comma and a space. The split method turns the string into an array of elements e.g. ['a, ', 'b']. Again notice how only the first element includes a comma followed by a space. The second map loops through the array using the rails helper content_tag to provide some html code for each element.  The content tag is appended to the html variable for displaying in the view.